# Shorten SVG path arc by pixel

Tags: d3.js, svg, geometry, 2d, calc

I have a path with an arc that points to a circle:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="300" height="200">
<path d="M10,10  A120,120 0 0,0 200,100" stroke="green" stroke-width="5" fill="none" />
<circle cx="200" cy="100" r="10" stroke="black" stroke-width="5" fill="none" />
</svg>
```

Now I want that the path ends e.g. 20 pixel (or a few degree, if simpler) before the border of the circle:

[image: rendered SVG with arrow with note "Line should end here"]

How can I archive this? How can I calculate the differing X and Y as target for the arc drawing (in my example the `200,100` in the `d` argument)?

In the end I will do this with [D3](https://d3js.org/), so I need an algorithm.

Answer (score 5):

This could easily be done by applying a variation of the `stroke-dasharray` [trick](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/s/stroke-dasharray/). You can obtain the total length of the path by calling [`.getTotalLength()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SVGPathElement/getTotalLength), subtract the length you want the path to end before this calculated length, and set the [`stroke-dasharray`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/stroke-dasharray) attribute accordingly:

```js
var path = d3.select("path")
  .attr("stroke-dasharray", function() { 
    return this.getTotalLength() - 20;
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.js"></script>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="300" height="200">
<path d="M10,10  A120,120 0 0,0 200,100" stroke="green" stroke-width="5" fill="none" stroke-dasharray="100"/>
<circle cx="200" cy="100" r="10" stroke="black" stroke-width="5" fill="none" />
</svg>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do this via a geometric algorithm, you will have to first compute the arc's properties such as center (cx, cy), start angle, sweeping angle,...etc from the current available data: radius = 120, start point (10, 10), end point (200, 100) and the two flags (large arc flag and sweep flag). Please refer to section F6.5 in this [link](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/implnote.html#ArcConversionEndpointToCenter) for details.  Once you have these information, you can compute the new end point easily.